# How to return an ID from firestore collections

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

At the moment, I'm fetching documents from my firestore collection but if I set an ID generally it won't return anything, until I hardcode the ID in the Doc, here's my code...

```js
useEffect(() =>{
    // LISTEN (REALTIME)
    const fetchData = async (id) =>{
      const docRef = doc(db, "users" , "DRrJ5zVL1YdP4wVs32aC");
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const theData = docSnap.data();
        console.log('getUserDoc() setting userInfo:', theData);
        setUserInfo(theData);
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }

    fetchData();
    }, [id]);
```

I have a lot of documents in my collection and I want to only retrieve the required ID when I'm to update a doc..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What doesn't work about the code you shared? Is there an error message? If not, did you debug it locally already? So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I have several ID, I don't want to hardcode an ID, I want to dynamically fetch those ID once it's clicked

Comment: Did you try `const docRef = doc(db, "users" , id);`?

Comment: Yes! It did not work

Comment: "it did not work" is really hard to help with. If there was no error message, use the approach I gave in my first comment to debug the problem and find exactly what variable on what line isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: I'm getting the error of, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"

Comment: That typically happens if `if` is `undefined`. Please debug locally, as the best way to find this out is in the local debugger, by inspecting the variables. You'll see that `id` is empty when you pass it to Firestore.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that the useParams is not detecting the Id the Id that is clearly present in the url

Comment: That was what was causing the issue, finally resolved it from the console.. Thanks bro.. so pumped 

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken what you want to do is fetch the documents without referencing an id.
For that you will need to use, getDocs() rather than getDoc.
This will allow you to query a collection of items rather than a single item.
Here is a snippet from the firebase docs:

```
import { collectionGroup, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";  

const museums = query(collectionGroup(db, 'landmarks'), where('type', '==', 'museum'));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(museums);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
```

Comment: This would require a collectionGroup once I run it

Comment: Just replace collectionGroup with collection..

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try `const docRef = doc(db, "users" , id)`?

> > I'm getting the error of, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"

That typically happens if `id` is undefined. Please debug locally, as the best way to find this out is in the local debugger, by inspecting the variables.

Set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line to determine the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do.

You'll see that `id` is empty when you pass it to Firestore.